# доступ к полям класса через функцию типа того же класса

Tags: c++, ооп

код плохой но вот мой вопрос :КАК МНЕ ЧЕРЕЗ ТИП ФУНКЦИИ ВЕРНУТЬ ЕГО ПОЛЯ ИЛИ МЕТОДЫ

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
    int a = 5;
    
}

A test(){
    return a;
}

int main(){

    cout<<test();
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Непонятно чего вы хотите, хотите иметь доступ к полю `int` делайте функцию возвращающую `int`,  Что значит вернуть метод? Указатель на функцию? Тогда делайте метод с возвращаемым типом - указатель на функцию

Answer (score 4):

Вам стоит прочитать о методах класса, и как с ними работать, это самые базовые понятия которые нужны.

В вашем коде `A` это всего лишь тип, для того что бы получить из него что-то вам необходимо иметь его экземпляр, без экземпляра вы ничего не сделаете.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
private:
    int a = 5;

public:
    int test() const;    
}

int A::test() const {
    return a;
}

int main() {
    A a; // экземпляр класса, который расположен в стеке.
    ::std::cout << a.test() << '\n'; // вызов метода у этого экземпляра и вывод значения
    
    return 0;
}
```

Хм, тут я додумал что вы хотите из простой глобальной функции получить что-то из класса? Увы, это невозможно если у вас нет экземпляра объекта.

Можно было бы сделать как-то так?

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    int a = 5;   
}

A a;

A test() {
    return a;
}

int main() {
    
    ::std::cout << test().a << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A test(){
return a;}
```

Тут вы почти были на правильном пути. Только вы не создали этот `test` что бы к нему можно было обращатся. А так ответ выше дает вам полный ответ, но думаю вам пока лучше использовать методы класа описывывая их в самом класе чем выносить из за предел класа.